# What's the difference between these two pins?

Tags: gui-design, icons, maps

See attached picture. The two types of pins all come from the keyword "pin" on google search. For me, the first one (without black line) is more related to existing shops on a map while another is more like when a user makes an action (with the black line). The third image is of Uber pins on a map, shows exactly what I mean.

I was wondering if you could use a mix of the two, for example, use the without black line pin to do "pin it" action, because there is no definition yet on the difference?

[image: pin without black line][image: pin with black line][image: uber example]

Comment: Well as far as I know the first is called a "marker" and the latter a "pin", so I guess you could make the semantic difference between marking something and pinning something but I think it's typically a design choice.

Comment: @DasBeasto if uber use "marker" to do " pin a location" to request a taxi, will you feel it still same in feeling on the design?

Comment: I would say it's mostly a matter of skeuomorphic vs flat. I wouldn't mix the two but I'd read the two largely the same. The flat (left) one is much more common though (and easier to append extra information on top of).

Answer (score 3):

To me the second one is an indicator of selection and the first one is a more generic pointer (that is sometimes used as a selection as well).

So the first one can be used in many different things, but the second one I would only use to indicate selection.

Answer (score 1):

**The icons seem to be used for the same purpose, marking a location on the map.**

The left image icon is the Google Maps location marker. I don't recognize the right icon, but based off the light reflection effect of the icon, I'm going to assume that it is from an older map system (just a guess).

You make a good reference to the Uber Map display, as it seems to combine the two designs into one, shown below:

[image]

The pin is a mapping of the real world use of using pins to mark locations on a physical map. With the pin needles being small and thin, you can precisely place a pin on a map, without it being ambiguous as to what location the pin is marking. The status of the pin being "pushed in" fully or not doesn't necessarily matter, just the state of it being in a particular location.

Answer (score 1):

The marker on the left hand side would be used for information marking (restaurants, gyms, etc)

The pin on the right I would say would be used for more finding exact locations of things. Like people on their phones waiting for an uber pickup

As far as mixing them I don't see the difference as well, its more up to why you would mix them together. If it meets the needs of your project, then go for it.

Answer (score 1):

I really think the only difference is the style. The first image is a closer to material design, flat design. The second is a representation closer to the physical object.

Comment: those two imgs were grab from google seach, actually can find the same style for both of them. Sorry if the image styles made some confusion here.